# My table view does not navigate to another uiview page. What might be wrong?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My table view cells have the `ContentView` as the Labels. When I click on them to navigate to another view whose `viewController` is as shown does not navigate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailedWebViewController *detailedWebViewTab1=[[DetailedWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedRssWebView" bundle:Nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedWebViewTab1 animated:NO];
    [detailedWebViewTab1 release];
}
```

- on tap it stays where it is highlighting the table in blue.
- the object for the XIB is being created but cannot navigate to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check in debugger if your detailedWebViewTab1 is really not nil. It seems to be so according to your description.